# How to intersect two raw SQL queries using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have two raw Postgresql statements.

```
q1 = "SELECT name FROM table_a"
q2 = "SELECT name FROM table_b"
```

How can I query the intersection of them using SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more or less what you could do:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@localhost/somedb')
q1 = "SELECT name FROM table_a intersect SELECT name FROM table_b"
q1res = engine.execute(text(q1)).fetchall()
# or
q2res = engine.execute(text(q1)).fetchone()
```

Depending on your needs. Ditch `fetchone` and `fetchall` if you intend to make inserts or updates.

Comment: I'd like to be able to generate the SQL statement that includes the INTERSECT inside the query, and execute it that way, rather than fetching all the results from both and having python deal with intersects.

Comment: Well since you are performing raw queries, simply add an intersection. I've updated the answer. Also you could have a look at sqlalchemy's orm which is extremely powerful: [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.intersect)